# sql query with group and right join on other column return Error - Ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, group-by

I have two table lets say 'Table1' contains three column with ' famile_typ' , 'KW 19' , 'KW 210' 
and another table 'Table2' Contains only one column with 'Famile' which contains 5 rows.

I would like to select family typ from table 2 with KW 20 and KW 21 from table1.

```
Table2 

ID Familie

2 Steuerung
3 Machine
4 packet
5 Skid
6 Gripper


Table1

famile    KW20   KW19

Machine     5     0
Skid       155   235
Steuerung   0    110
```

I would like to an ouput with contain all values from table2 with kw 20 and kw19 from table1

output table

```
Famile     KW20   KW19

Steuerung   0     110
Machine     5      0
packet      0      0
Skid       155    235
Gripper     0      0
```

I have tried right join but it shows the empty field with #Error. like as below

```
Famile     KW20   KW19

Steuerung   0     110
Machine     5      0
           Empty  Empty
Skid       155    235
           Empty  Empty
```

I am not expert when it comes to query with joins and multiple query.

Comment: Show the query you have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select t2.Familie, nz(t1.KW20, 0) as KW20, nz(t1.KW19, 0) as KW19
from table2 as t2 left join
     table1 as t1
     on t2.Familie = t1.Familie;
```